# Grabbing a number of characters around a string pattern

Tags: pattern-matching, string-manipulation, text

If I have some string data:

```
text = StringTake[ExampleData[{"Text", "DeclarationOfIndependence"}], 400]
```

> "When in the Course of human events, it becomes necessary for one 
>      people to dissolve the political bands which have connected them with 
>      another, and to assume, among the Powers of the earth, the separate 
>      and equal station to which the Laws of Nature and of Nature's God 
>      entitle them, a decent respect to the opinions of mankind requires 
>      that they should declare the causes which impel them to the sepa"

This is what I use to find a specific pattern inside and grab a bit more data around it:

```
StringCases[text, (y__ /;StringLength[y] == 4) ~~ "entitle" ~~ x__ /;StringLength[x] == 5]
```

> ```
> {"God entitle them"}
> ```

**Are there any alternatives, desirably neater ones? Maybe something with regular expressions?**

Comment: So `StringTake[text, First[StringPosition[text, "entitle"]] + {-4, 5}]` isn't neat?

Comment: @J.M. It is, you should post it as an answer - I am looking for tidbits like this ;-) Hoping to get something with regular expressions too.

Comment: regexes in my answer

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Per Vitaliy's request:

```
With[{before = 4, after = 5},
 StringTake[text, First[StringPosition[text, "entitle"]] + {-before, after}]]
```

yields `"God entitle them"`.

Answer (score 12):

Using regular expressions

```
f[text_, string_, before_, after_] := 
 StringCases[text, RegularExpression[".{" <> ToString@before <> "}" <> 
                                     string <> ".{" <> ToString@after <> "}"]]

f[text, "entitle", 4, 5]

(*{"God entitle them"}*)
```

---

(added by J. M.)

A more compact implementation of the function `f[]` is as follows:

```
f[text_String, string_String, before_Integer, after_Integer] :=
  StringCases[text, RegularExpression[ToString[StringForm[
              ".{`1`}" <> string <> ".{`2`}", before, after]]]]
```

The `ToString[]` is needed here since `StringForm[]`, contrary to how it is named, does **not** return a `String[]` object, and thus a conversion has to be done.

Comment: Great thanks ;-) So `".{4}entitle.{5}"` - is such notation mentioned in docs? It seems I've missed it.

Comment: @VitaliyKaurov The Regexp docs in the Mma help system are good, but not enough to learn regexes from zero.

Comment: @VitaliyKaurov The documentation [mentions](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/WorkingWithStringPatterns.html#274403895) that Mathematica's regular expressions are implemented using PCRE.  The [PCRE](http://www.pcre.org/pcre.txt) and [Perl regex](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) man pages accurately document Mathematica's regex features.

Comment: Here's an alternative implementation: ````f[text_, string_, before_, after_] := StringCases[text, RegularExpression[ToString[StringForm[".{`1`}" <> string <> ".{`2`}", before, after]]]]````

Comment: @J.M. `StringForm` is one of those zillions of little Mma functions that make life easier, but I keep forgetting. As it is a real improvement (at least in readability), please consider to post an answer or edit mine.

Comment: It's still your idea, so I elected to just edit instead of posting my own answer.

Answer (score 12):

```
StringCases[text, x___ ~~ "entitle" ~~ y___ :> 
   StringTake[x, -4] ~~ "entitle" ~~ StringTake[y, 5]]
```

or

```
StringCases[text, Repeated[_, 4] ~~ "entitle" ~~ Repeated[_, 5]]
```

Generalizing:

```
paddedString1[text_, string_, left_, right_] := 
 StringCases[text,  x___ ~~ string ~~ y___ :> 
  StringTake[x, -left] ~~ string ~~ StringTake[y, right]]
```

and

```
paddedString2[text_, string_, left_, right_] := 
 StringCases[text, Repeated[_, {left}] ~~ string ~~ Repeated[_, {right}]]
```

Comment: Interesting twist, thanks ;-)

Comment: I think the last one should be `Repeated[_, {left}] ~~ string ~~ Repeated[_, {right}]`? `Repeated[_, n]` means "repeated **up to** *n* times"; `Repeated[_, {n}]` is **exactly** *n*.

Comment: @OleksandrR., you are right ... Thank you. I thought --wrongly -- that `n` versus `{n}` would not make a difference for the pattern `_` and chose to save some keystrokes.

Comment: @Oleksandr when would the original produce an incorrect result?  I find the behavior of the original highly desirable in that it gracefully handles sub-strings at the beginning and end of the text.  If this were my question I would Accept this answer (in its original form) for that reason.

Comment: kguler, by the way, I happened to check your profile and you've been here *every single day* since the beginning.  I don't know whether I should congratulate you or arrange an intervention.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, MMA.SE is one of the opening tabs in my browser - just realized the browser happened to be open too many consecutive days. I will take this as - much needed - intervention:)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I agree with you that often one might prefer not to require a fixed amount of padding. However, the code in the question requires an exact number of characters either side, so arguably a reformulation using `Repeated` should be semantically identical.