# How do I use wildcard characters with StringTake?

Tags: string-manipulation

Say I'd like to pick substrings from some string such that these substrings have the pattern `@@@q@@@`, where `@` is used here as a stand-in for a 'wildcard' character (i.e. any character) and `q` is just an example of a specific character that can be specified as desired.

The kind of lame solution might be as follows:

```
substringList = StringTake[testString, # + {-3, 3} & /@ StringPosition[testString, "q"]];
```

This, of course, runs into trouble when `q` appears near one of the two ends of `testString`.
What's the correct way to do this?

Comment: Have you seen `StringCases`? The tutorials at the bottom of the `StringCases` documentation (specifically, the ones on String Patterns) will also come in useful.

Comment: @Aky I'm actually looking through that now, however it's not clear how to specify wildcard sequences flanking some character of interest?  For example, this pattern "a" ~~ x_ ~~ "c" is workable, but how do we ask for something like my example ~~~x~~~~?

Comment: @CA30 `~` joins patterns only. p.s. is each wildcard different?

Comment: @Kuba Yes, here each 'wildcard' can be different.  It just means "I don't care what's here, return it."  But it does have to mean that 'some' character is there.  We can't run off the ends of the string!

Comment: Try something like `StringCases["acaqaddqccxjq", RegularExpression["...q..."], 
 Overlaps -> True]`, which returns `{"acaqadd", "addqccx"}`

Comment: @Aky Hmm, seems to work, what's going on with this expression?

Comment: It's just using regular expression (regexps). The . is a single character wildcard (equivalent to your @). If you aren't familiar with regular expressions, you can read up on them. (They're a computer scienc-y tool, not specific to just `Mathematica`)

Comment: @Aky Thanks, still pretty cool.  What is Overlaps doing?

Comment: It's in the `StringCases` documentation. If you leave out `Overlaps -> True` (which is the same as saying `Overlaps -> False`) the second substring is not outputted, because its first three characters ("add") overlap with the last three characters of the first matched substring.

Comment: @Aky Got it, thanks.

Comment: Related [Grabbing a number of characters around a string pattern](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/9246/125)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please reference: [How do I perform string matching and replacements?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6998/121)

Using [`StringExpression`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/StringExpression.html):

```
string = ExampleData[{"Text", "DeclarationOfIndependence"}];

StringCases[string, _ ~~ _ ~~ _ ~~ "q" ~~ _ ~~ _ ~~ _]
```

> ```
> {"d equal", " requir", "d equal", "linquis", "or quar", " acquie"}
> ```

Or:

```
StringCases[string, # ~~ "q" ~~ #] & @ Repeated[_, {3}]
```

> ```
> {"d equal", " requir", "d equal", "linquis", "or quar", " acquie"}
> ```

Using [`RegularExpression`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/RegularExpression.html) as already shown by [Aky](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/6683/aky):

```
StringCases[string, RegularExpression["...q..."]]
```

> ```
> {"d equal", " requir", "d equal", "linquis", "or quar", " acquie"}
> ```

Or as I just (re)discovered using `` StringPattern`PatternConvert `` as noted in the comments below:

```
StringCases[string, RegularExpression[".{3}q.{3}"]]
```

> ```
> {"d equal", " requir", "d equal", "linquis", "or quar", " acquie"}
> ```

Comment: Wasn't aware that `Repeated` worked with string patterns too.. +1.

Comment: @Aky That's the beauty of `StringExpression`: you can use nearly all of the native *Mathematica* pattern operators in application to strings.  Regular Expressions are often shorter for those well accustomed to them, but since I am not it usually takes me less time to write the `StringExpression` equivalent.  *Mathematica* actually converts the `StringExpression` to a Regular Expression before handing off the operation to an optimized string library.  You can see what is produced using ``StringPattern`PatternConvert``.  For example: (continued)

Comment: ``First @ StringPattern`PatternConvert[Repeated[_, {3}] ~~ "q" ~~ Repeated[_, {3}]]`` yields `"(?ms).{3}q.{3}"`.  You can use this to learn how to write `RegularExpression` patterns.  `(?ms)` has to do with multi-line behavior; `.{3}` is the concise form of `Repeated[_, {3}]` in RE language.

Comment: cool beans! I had no idea about all this.

Comment: @Aky As always, I'm glad I could help. :-)