# Extract substrings with defined length from a string

Tags: string-manipulation

I have a string like this one

```
str = "this and that but also thit and that";
```

Now I want to extract, the first 3 letters before and after " and " so that the outcome is

```
{his and tha, hit and tha}
```

I tried it with

```
StringCases[str, 
 x__ ~~ " and " ~~ y__ :> {StringTake[x, -3], StringTake[y, 3]}]
```

but this extracts only the second substring `{{"hit", "tha"}}`. And using `StringCases[str, _ ~~ " and " ~~ _]` extracts only one letter `{"s and t", "t and t"}`. So is there a way to define a `Blank` with a particular length?

Comment: possible duplicate: [Grabbing a number of characters around a string pattern](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/9246/125)

Comment: @kglr you are right. However, did not found that...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
StringCases[str,   x__ ~~ " and " ~~ y__ /; StringLength[x] == StringLength[y] == 3]
```

or

```
StringCases[str, _ ~~ _ ~~ _ ~~ " and " ~~ _ ~~ _ ~~ _]
```

would work:

> ```
> {"his and tha", "hit and tha"}
> ```

Answer (score 6):

Using `Repeated`:

```
StringCases[
 str,
 Repeated[_, {3}] ~~ " and " ~~ Repeated[_, {3}],
 Overlaps -> True
 ]
```

> `{"his and tha", "hit and tha"}`

Note the use of `Overlaps` which is necessary for strings such as

```
str = "this and that and thit and that";
```

With `Overlaps -> True`:

> `{"his and tha", "hat and thi", "hit and tha"}`

with `Overlaps -> False`:

> `{"his and tha", "hit and tha"}`

Comment: Your solution is neater and more detailed!

Answer (score 2):

If the number of whitespaces before and after 'and' is unknown (but in each case there is at least one), a simple regex should do:

```
str = "this and that but also thit and that";
StringCases[str, RegularExpression[".{3}\s+and\s+.{3}"]]
```

> {his and tha, hit and tha}

Alternatively, a positive lookahead may be used:

```
StringCases[str, RegularExpression["(?=(.{3}\s+and\s+.{3}))\\1"]]
StringCases[str, RegularExpression["(?=(.{3}\s+and\s+.{3}))"]:> "$1"]
```

> {his and tha, hit and tha}

> {his and tha, hit and tha}

---

For strings such as "this and that and thit and that" considered by [C.E](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/731/c-e) [above](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/225050/106):

```
str2 = "this and that and thit and that";
StringCases[str2, RegularExpression[".{3}\s+and\s+.{3}"], Overlaps:> True]
StringCases[str2, RegularExpression["(?=(.{3}\s+and\s+.{3}))\\1"],Overlaps->True]
StringCases[str2, RegularExpression["(?=(.{3}\s+and\s+.{3}))"]:> "$1"]
```

> {his and tha, hat and thi, hit and tha}

> {his and tha, hat and thi, hit and tha}

> {his and tha, hat and thi, hit and tha}

In addition [posix character classes](https://regular-expressions.mobi/posixbrackets.html?wlr=1) are supported:

```
StringCases[str2, RegularExpression["[[:alnum:]]{3}[[:blank:]][Aa]nd[[:blank:]][[:alnum:]]{3}"], Overlaps:> True]
```

> {his and tha, hat and thi, hit and tha}

---

For positive lookaheads, compare (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5616910/499167)):

```
s = "123456789123456789";
StringCases[s,RegularExpression["(?=(\d{10}))\\1"]]
StringCases[s,RegularExpression["(?=(\d{10}))\\1"],Overlaps:>True]
StringCases[s,RegularExpression["(?=(\d{10}))"]:> "$1"]
```

> {1234567891}

> {1234567891, 2345678912, 3456789123, 4567891234, 5678912345, 6789123456, 7891234567, 8912345678, 9123456789}

> {1234567891, 2345678912, 3456789123, 4567891234, 5678912345, 6789123456, 7891234567, 8912345678, 9123456789}